# Здравствуйте. Надо из NodeList получить Integer

Tags: java, парсер, sax

Есть следующая реализация кода:

```
NodeList rightsNodeList = docsRightsParent.getElementsByTagName("DOC");

        for (int i = 0; i < rightsNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = rightsNodeList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                clients.put(((Element) node).getAttribute("qwe"), node.getTextContent());
            }
        }
```

Для получения:

```
    <DOCS>
        <DOC qwe="qq">15</DOC>
        <DOC qwe="qq">16</DOC>
    </DOCS>
```

Есть ли способ место node.getTextContent() без парсера, получить Integer(не String) значения 15 и 16?

Comment: А чем не устраивает строка?

Comment: @RomanDanilov такова цель задания) если честно я бы распарсил и все... но для оптимизации просто хочу поинтересоваться есть ли такой способ, или нет.... и если есть, то какой

Comment: Только Integer.valueOf(anyString);

Comment: @RomanDanilov спасибо) теперь моя совесть чиста) напиши в ответе, чтобы я плюсик поставил)

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) у класса Node нет вариантов получить контент внутри тега кроме как строкой.
Используйте метод `Integer.valueOf(String s)`